# Could anyone help me to explain this quote?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, clauses

I have read this quote:

> The difference in winning & losing **is** most often, **not quitting**.

I am so curious for some issue below.

- I wonder why "**not**", as in "**not quitting**", has a comma in front
  of "**not**"?
- whether "**quitting**" is a present participle or a gerund?
- Does meaning of this sentence change if "**not**" is placed after "**is**"?
- Is "**not quitting**" a reduced form of an adjective clause?
- Is it possible that "**not quitting**" comes from "**The difference which doesn't quit in winning & losing is most often**"?

PS. Thank you in advance for answering my question and I am so sorry if I make you confused.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo and there is a missing comma after "is". "The difference in winning & losing is **,** most often, not quitting.

Comment: The comma is misplaced.  Either there should be two or none at all.

Comment: "Often, the difference between winning and losing is simply not giving up on the task at hand."

Comment: The sentence, as @MarkHubbard points out, means that 'generally, if you don't quit, you'll win' (rather than any external influence deciding on whether you win or lose). Technically, it will still make sense if you replace 'not' with 'is', although motivational quotes tend to focus on the positive outcome! (if you replace 'not' with 'is', it implies that quitting is what you *should* do). Also, your last sentence doesn't really make sense - think of the original as 2 parts: 'the difference *between* winning and losing', 'is most often' (subordinate clause, not really needed), 'not quitting'.

Comment: [cont] so you can rearrange the above bits, like: 'not quitting is most often the difference between winning and losing' (I prefer '*between*', '*in*' makes sense too though), or: 'most often, the difference between winning and losing is not quitting'. I hope this helps!

Comment: Since winning and losing are opposites, and certainly not a pair, the use of the & to replace 'and' is literally too cute for words.  Hot & pungent, yes; sweet & sour, yes; black & white cookies, definitely.  Just saying.

Comment: The comma shows that "not" belongs with "quitting"; otherwise the sentence might be understood to say "The difference _is not_ quitting (but _is_ something else).

Comment: Please **do not cross-post questions** on [more than one site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133704/could-anyone-help-me-to-explain-this-quote). If a question might be relevant to more than one, decide which is best and post the question. But only post it once. Also, you have not cited the source of your quote in this version: context is often necessary, and copyright rules and even common courtesy mean that the source should be acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The comma before "not" is used to group "not quitting" instead of "is not." It's an odd way to use a comma, but without it, this quote would be confusing.
- "Quitting" is most closely used as a gerund.
- Changing the sentence from "is 'not quitting'" to "'is not' quitting" changes the meaning from "not quitting is the difference between winning and losing" to "quitting is not the difference between winning and losing," which is a complete reversal!
- "Not quitting" is a gerund, and as such, is treated as a noun.
- The writer most likely used "not quitting" to emphasize that "not quitting" makes one a "winner," rather than emphasizing that "quitting" making one a "loser."